# Can't connect to wifi on Debian Jessie with wpa_supplicant: ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument

Tags: debian, wifi, usb, wpa-supplicant, ndiswrappers

I can't connect to my wireless LAN with my usb wifi, via ifplugd or wpa_supplicant. My *wpa_supplicant.conf* content:

```
  ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

  network={
  driver=wext
  ssid="myessid"
  scan_ssid=1
  proto=WPA
  pairwise=TKIP
  group=TKIP
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
  psk="mypassphrase"
 }
```

The command I use:

```
 wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -Dwext -cwpa_supplicant
```

The output:

```
 Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
 ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
 ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

At the same time, the **iwevent wlan0** output is:

```
 Waiting for Wireless Events from interfaces...
 17:02:53.825711   wlan0    Set Mode:Managed
 17:02:53.826035   wlan0    Set ESSID:"g\xC6isQ\xFFJ\xEC)\xCD\xBA\xAB\xF2\xFB\xE3F|\xC2T\xF8\x1B\xE8\xE7\x8DvZ.c3\x9F\xC9\x9A"
```

Also, **iwpriv wlan0** shows the following:

```
wlan0     Available private ioctls :
      ndis_reset       (8BF0) : set   0       & get   0      
      power_profile    (8BF1) : set   1 int   & get   0      
      deauthenticate   (8BF3) : set   0       & get   0      
      network_type     (8BF2) : set   1 char  & get   0      
      media_stream     (8BF4) : set   1 int   & get   0      
      reload_defaults  (8BF7) : set   0       & get   0
```

I am using ndiswrapper.

My device:

```
 Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0457:0163 Silicon Integrated Systems Corp. 802.11 Wireless LAN Adapter
```

Ndiswrapper output:

```
 sis163u : driver installed
device (0457:0163) present
```

Ndiswrapper is loaded at startup by modprobe.

And my iwconfig output is:

```
 wlan0     IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Tx-Power:16 dBm   Sensitivity=0/3  
      RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

EDIT: I was doing it wrong. I should've used the -c parameter instead of -C. But unfortunately, the problem its essentially the same.

Answer (score 2):

The output of your `wpa_supplicant` command ends with this:

```
You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.
```

...which should be pretty obvious. You need to check whether there's already a `wpa_supplicant` running. Do so by way of:

```
pgrep wpa_supplicant
```

If that produces some output, then you need to `kill` the process ID that `pgrep` gave you. If it does not, then you need to clean up the file which `wpa_supplicant` tries to make.

If that doesn't fix it, then please post the output after having done the above (in your original post, not as a comment)

Comment: `killall wpa_supplicant` should solve the problem

Comment: In 99% of cases, yes. I try to accommodate for the 1% where that isn't sufficient as well...